# Shell Script -kill all process by name but me

Tags: shell-script, kill

I have shell script `test.sh` that I running.

I want that in the beginning of this script ,if there are  older `test.sh` that running ,kill them first.

If I killall `test.sh` the newest process killed too.

I there any simple way to do it ?

Comment: Is this on a Linux system?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

term_handler () {
    if [ "$ok_to_exit" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo 'exiting'
        exit
    else
        echo 'refusing to exit'
    fi
}

trap term_handler TERM

ok_to_exit=0
pkill -f test.sh
ok_to_exit=1

while true; do
    echo 'working...'
    sleep 2
done
```

This script (of which there is a simpler version below) installs a signal handler, the `term_handler` function, which will exit the script upon receiving a `TERM` signal *if* the `ok_to_exit` variable's value is `1`.

In the body of the script is a loop simulating some form of work being carried out.  The important bit is that before calling `pkill` (you may change this to your `killall` command), it sets `ok_to_exit` to `0`, and directly afterwards it sets it to `1`.

When sending out the `TERM` signal to all matching processes, it will receive the signal itself, but it will refuse to exit.  Any other matching processes, *if it's not also in the exact same state* (which could happen if you started the script more than once simultaneously), would terminate.

When running, this script would output

```
refusing to exit
working...
working...
working...
```

When another copy of the script is started, it outputs `exiting` and then terminates.

A simpler version of the same script:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap '' TERM
pkill -f test.sh
trap - TERM

while true; do
    echo 'working...'
    sleep 2
done
```

This simply *ignores* the `TERM` signal during the call to `pkill`, and then reinstates the default signal handler before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way without playing around with signal handlers is to signal every process but yourself:

```
for pid in $(pgrep ${0##*/}); do
    if [[ $pid -ne $$ ]]; then
        kill -s TERM $pid
    fi
done
```

If you're not terribly familiar with bash `${0##*/}` gives you the basename of `$0`, the name of your script invocation, so that "/path/to/test.sh" becomes "test.sh".

Answer (score 1):

You'd have some trouble getting more than two instances of these started, but you could use `pgrep`/`pkill` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ "$(pgrep -c -f test.sh)" -gt 1 ]
do
  pkill --oldest -f test.sh
done

# rest of your script
```

### Adjust the "test.sh" parameter to more precisely match the process name itself!

*For examples*:

`/bin/sh ./test.sh`

or

`/bin/sh /full/path/to/test.sh`

or

`/bin/bash ./test.sh`

or

`sh test.sh`

... so that you're not accidentally matching anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If **all** your executions of `test.sh` **always** pass through such a watchguard check then you could just do:

```bsh
pid=$(pgrep -o -f "/test.sh( |$)") && [ ${pid} -ne ${$} ] && kill $pid
```

The above line kills only the oldest execution unless it is exactly also the present execution, however it has been called.

But just in case you want to be absolutely sure that no previous executions ever slipped the check, you can put the above line in a `while` loop, like so:

```bsh
while pid=$(pgrep -o -f "/test.sh( |$)") && [ ${pid} -ne ${$} ] ; do
    kill $pid
done
```

The above kills **any** previous executions of `test.sh`, however they have been called.

Depending on your needs, you might like a selection criteria that also considers specific literal arguments of the command.

You may do so by including whatever arguments you want to check within the double-quotes, like so:

(*note: I'm showing only the `pgrep` part to use in the above code*)

`pgrep -o -f "/test.sh +arg1 +arg2 *$"`

The extra `+` and `*$` are required to match no more and no less than those exact arguments. (*In this example the literal strings `arg1` and `arg2`*).

You may also pass variables in, so for instance one desirable variant might be to kill only those previous executions that were run with the same arguments as the current execution:

`pgrep -o -f "/test.sh +${*} *$"`

Here the `${*}` translates to all arguments of the current execution.

Basically, the string within double-quotes can be any valid regular-expression, and this helps you match the exact execution(s) you want to kill, which is very important in order to avoid killing foreign processes.